# Crystal Report Page header suppress issue

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2008, suppress

I need to suppress the page header when there are no records in the detail section.I have used

```
onLastRecord
```

at page header->section expert->suppress.it works fine but issue is when there is only one record in the detail section.then page header is suppress how can i avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question requires more detail.

Anyway, based on what I have understood, I would suggest any of these ways to sort out this issue.

1. Add a count() function formula to the suppress section. Find details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287759/suppress-crystal-reports-section-if-there-are-no-rows-in-a-datatable).
2. Add a condition like OnLastRecord or {GROUP FIELD NAME} <> Next({GROUP FIELD NAME}).   Find details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294027/crystal-reports-suppress-a-page-header-if-the-page-has-0-records).
3. Check for IsNull({table.field}) of a non-null field.
4. Check whether the DisctinctCount of the PK field is null.

Comment: "OnLastRecord AND Count({dtSquadCheckDetails.DocumentNumber})  <>  1" on page header->section expert->suppress worked for me.Thanks